# PDO SQLite create database default permissions

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, file-permissions

When using PDO sqlite PHP adapter, new sqlite database file is created with group permission set to read-only, and does not honor umask.

I need every database file to be writable by group. Any way to accomplish it?

Edit: I know how to change permissions of a file, I'm asking whether it is possible to create it with correct permissions (according to process umask) or not.

Comment: You could change permissions of database file after creation of it by using `chmod`

Comment: Thanks, I know :)
File is created not in my script, but by third-party library, TYPO3 Flow, and is used for caching. So no, I can't chown.

Comment: Then you need to change the permissions on those files... Or change the Apache user and/or group to the same user and/or group as the process creating those files.

Comment: I can't. Too long to explain in detail: files are created on first page hit, and not during deployment, I need that file to be editable by both shell user and nginx and so on... That's not relevant to question asked anyways.

Comment: I'm digging in direction of SQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS, let's see where it ends up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's a `SQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS` [compilation parameter](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html).

It seems [umask is applied on top of it](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/about-default-file-permission-of-SQLite-database-file-td19582.html) to restrict it, if necessary.
So it makes sense to recompile with `SQLITE_DEFAULT_FILE_PERMISSIONS=666` and than rely on umask. Too bad it's not a default option in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

Before opening the database file using sqlite's connect call, you can open is as an ordinary file and the desired permissions. This will create an empty file unless the file is already present. Sqlite will fill that empty file with the database.

This is safer than using `chmod` after the file has been created for two reasons:

- There is a tiny possibility that another user could open the file before you call `chmod`
- In some cases (e.g. when configured for WAL), sqlite will create more than one file. It will honor the permissions of the pre-existing empty file and use them for the other files. Using `chmod` on the main file would forget to set permissions for the other files.